# Calculate values and draw lines based on fixed timeframe - PineScript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I draw some lines that should be calculated on a fixed timeframe(for example "1D"). My code is as below:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="testing-pressure and support", overlay=true)

//中心价和 K 线振幅
float mid_price = (high + low) / 2
float diff      = high - low 

//support price
float support1  = mid_price - 0.618 * diff
float support2  = mid_price - 1 * diff

//压力位
float pressure1 = mid_price + 0.618 * diff
float pressure2 = mid_price + 1 * diff

//是否显示支撑位和压力位
show_support = input.bool(title="显示支撑位", defval=true) 
show_pressure = input.bool(title="显示压力位", defval=true) 
show_mid_price = input.bool(title="显示中心价", defval=true) 

//固定一个时间周期
timeframe = input.timeframe(defval="D", title="固定时间周期")
float d_support1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support1)
float d_support2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support2)
float d_pressure1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure1)
float d_pressure2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure2)
float d_mid_price = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, mid_price)
bool d_barstate =  request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, barstate.islast)

//绘制支撑位和压力位
line_length = input.int(defval=10, title="支撑/压力线的长度")

if d_barstate
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support1[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support1[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support1[1], text=str.tostring(d_support1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support2[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support2[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support2[1], text=str.tostring(support2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
  

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure1[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], text=str.tostring(pressure1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure2[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], text=str.tostring(d_pressure2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_mid_price[1], bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], color = show_mid_price ? color.yellow : na, width = 1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], text=str.tostring(mid_price[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
```

when the chart is in 1D timeframe, the indicator is showing like this:
[image]

then I switch it to 4H, it is like this:
[image]

it seems that the lines keep changing while chart timeframe changes, but I want them to be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input property to specify a time frame and use it throughout your script:

```
dtf = input("D", title = "Time Frame")
```

Substitute what you want into "D" to update the chart with that time frame (ex. "W" for weekly). With this, you could create a very simple script that labels the previous days high on your chart:

```
//@version=5
indicator("previous day high", overlay=true)

dtf = input("D", title = "TimeFrame")

// checks if its a new bar in the selected dtf timeframe
is_new_bar(t) => 
    ta.change(time(t)) != 0

getDailyHigh() =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, dtf, high[1])

var float dailyHigh = na
if is_new_bar(dtf)
    dailyHigh := getDailyHigh()

// places label
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, dailyHigh, text = str.tostring(dailyHigh), style = label.style_label_down, color = color.blue, textcolor = color.white, yloc = yloc.price)
```

This chart looks as follows:
[image]

The chart above isnt wildly useful, but it is a simple example on the road to accomplish what you want. We will use the same logic, including the daily low, to calculate all the values in your chart.

Now, grabbing the daily high and daily low as above, and plotting values derived from them:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="testing-pressure and support", overlay=true)

dtf = input("D", title = "TimeFrame")
 
// checks if its a new bar in the selected dtf timeframe
is_new_bar(t) => 
    ta.change(time(t)) != 0
    

var float dailyHigh = na
var float dailyLow = na
getDailyHigh() =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, dtf, high[1])
getDailyLow() =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, dtf, low[1])
    
if is_new_bar(dtf)
    dailyHigh := getDailyHigh()
    dailyLow := getDailyLow()
    
var float previousDayHigh = na
var float previousDayLow = na

if is_new_bar("D")
    previousDayHigh := getDailyHigh()
    previousDayLow := getDailyLow()
float mid_price = (previousDayHigh + previousDayLow) / 2
float diff      = previousDayHigh - previousDayLow

//support price
float support1  = mid_price - 0.618 * diff
float support2  = mid_price - 1 * diff

//压力位
float pressure1 = mid_price + 0.618 * diff
float pressure2 = mid_price + 1 * diff

//是否显示支撑位和压力位
show_support = input.bool(title="显示支撑位", defval=true) 
show_pressure = input.bool(title="显示压力位", defval=true) 
show_mid_price = input.bool(title="显示中心价", defval=true) 

//固定一个时间周期
timeframe = input.timeframe(defval="D", title="固定时间周期")
float d_support1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support1)
float d_support2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support2)
float d_pressure1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure1)
float d_pressure2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure2)
float d_mid_price = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, mid_price)
bool d_barstate =  request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, barstate.islast)

//绘制支撑位和压力位
line_length = input.int(defval=10, title="支撑/压力线的长度")

if d_barstate
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support1[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support1[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support1[1], text=str.tostring(d_support1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support2[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support2[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support2[1], text=str.tostring(support2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
  

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure1[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], text=str.tostring(pressure1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure2[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], text=str.tostring(d_pressure2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_mid_price[1], bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], color = show_mid_price ? color.yellow : na, width = 1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], text=str.tostring(mid_price[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
```

You can see that the only changes are how the high and low are calculated, since every other value that is plotted relies on those two values. I am not positive if you are trying to use the previous days high and the previous days low, but that is what I used. If you are looking for the previous days close, then it would follow the same logic, but require a different method of data selection.
This chart looks as follows with the daily time frame selected:
[image]

And here I have selected a different time frame:
[image]

Its the same values!

It is possible that there is a way to do this more succinctly, as your script is now quite long, but I have taken enough time thus far that I do not wish to clean it up- if you are able to, though, I would be interested to see the final product.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts by explaining to me step by step. But still I have some doubts after I studied and tested your code on my tradingview. Would you mind to communicate more with me via some instant messaging（like telegram）to finally solve it for me? I will treat you  a cup of coffee by transfer you USDT(I know you don't need this but it is just for showing my thanks  to you ^_^). By the way it is amazing to get help from a stranger who is from the other side of the earth, haha.

Comment: @tang_bohu sorry tang but not very interested in that, happy to adjust this code though? What’s wrong with it?

Comment: First question: I want to add alarms for these supporting and pressure lines(once price touches any one of these lines then it alarms. Previously when I wrote other indicators I used "alarmcondition" function to create alarms. I also know "ta.crossover" function. But now I don't know how to express "price touches those lines" in pine language.

Comment: Second question: those lines always start from the last one bar no matter we switch our bar chart to which timeframe. When chart is "1D" timeframe, the lines start from the last one bar, that is to say yesterday's bar. When I switch the chart to "4H" or "1H" timeframe, the lines also start from last one bar which is the bar of 4hours or 1hour before. But I want the  lines to start from "today zero O'clock" no matter it is in "4H" or "1H" timeframe. Thank you.

Comment: @tang_bohu I will not write out the script for this, but within the script above, there is explicit calculation of where the lines are drawn. Therefore, if you can write an alarm to alert you at a given price, you can just reapply that logic to alert you near this dynamically-calculated value that we use to draw the line

Comment: For the first question which I mentioned above, If I draw one line via "plot" function, then I can add an alert based on that line(such like EMA line). But now in this indicator I draw lines vie the "line.new" function, and I didn't find a method to add an alert based on the lines. Can you help me on this?（I hope u understand my question....）

Answer (score 1):

To plot your lines only at the daily close, you can adjust the bottom if statement to check if its a new day, and also if its the last bar of that day:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="testing-pressure and support", overlay=true)

dtf = input("D", title = "TimeFrame")
 
// checks if its a new bar in the selected dtf timeframe
is_new_bar(t) => 
    ta.change(time(t)) != 0
    

var float dailyHigh = na
var float dailyLow = na
getDailyHigh() =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, dtf, high[1])
getDailyLow() =>
    request.security(syminfo.tickerid, dtf, low[1])
    
if is_new_bar(dtf)
    dailyHigh := getDailyHigh()
    dailyLow := getDailyLow()
    
var float previousDayHigh = na
var float previousDayLow = na

if is_new_bar("D")
    previousDayHigh := getDailyHigh()
    previousDayLow := getDailyLow()
float mid_price = (previousDayHigh + previousDayLow) / 2
float diff      = previousDayHigh - previousDayLow

//support price
float support1  = mid_price - 0.618 * diff
float support2  = mid_price - 1 * diff

//压力位
float pressure1 = mid_price + 0.618 * diff
float pressure2 = mid_price + 1 * diff

//是否显示支撑位和压力位
show_support = input.bool(title="显示支撑位", defval=true) 
show_pressure = input.bool(title="显示压力位", defval=true) 
show_mid_price = input.bool(title="显示中心价", defval=true) 

//固定一个时间周期
timeframe = input.timeframe(defval="D", title="固定时间周期")
float d_support1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support1)
float d_support2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, support2)
float d_pressure1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure1)
float d_pressure2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, pressure2)
float d_mid_price = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, mid_price)
bool d_barstate =  request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe, barstate.islast)

//绘制支撑位和压力位
line_length = input.int(defval=10, title="支撑/压力线的长度")

is_last_bar = bar_index == (bar_index[1] + 1)

if is_new_bar("D") and is_last_bar
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support1[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support1[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support1[1], text=str.tostring(d_support1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_support2[1], bar_index+line_length,d_support2[1], color = show_support ? color.green : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_support2[1], text=str.tostring(support2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
  

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure1[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure1[1], text=str.tostring(pressure1[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    
    line.new(bar_index-1, d_pressure2[1], bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], color = show_support ? color.red : na, width=1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_pressure2[1], text=str.tostring(d_pressure2[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
    

    line.new(bar_index-1, d_mid_price[1], bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], color = show_mid_price ? color.yellow : na, width = 1)
    label.new(bar_index+line_length, d_mid_price[1], text=str.tostring(mid_price[1]), xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none, color=color.green, textcolor=color.green, size=size.small)
```

You should adjust line length to suit your typical timeframe selection; when you choose higher time frames, this quickly gets cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

To set an alert relating to a line, you need to change your thoughts about what the "Line" is; the line is simply a price, and you want to be notified when it gets within some value of that price, right?

Therefore, if your `d_mid_price` line is at 45,000 USD, and you want an alert when the plot (price) is within 500USD of that line, then you can set an alert for when the plot is within +- 500USD of `d_mid_price` .

Apply the current code to fit into the structure of your alerts. Consider "lines" as "prices".

Comment: Do you mean that everyday I first check the line's value(suppose it is 45000USD), then I go to set an alert "when price come to 45000±500 it reminds me"? In this method, I have to set an alert everyday. But if I can set an alert related to a line, then I only need to set the alert once.

Comment: No, you are generating the value daily, and THEN setting the line based on that value, so you can set the alert based on the same value that the line is based on.